# How to swap caps-lock and escape keys

Tags: keyboard

I am using

- arch kernel 5.7.3-arch1-1, and
- openbox, and
- neo vim 0.4.3, and
- Lenovo thinkpad T430 laptop / keyboard.

All system packages are up to date.

I am trying to swap caps lock and escape keys for use in neoVim and have used this line

`setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape`

This sets the escape key as caps toggle as expected, but does nothing to the caps lock key.
I'm expecting that the caps lock key will work as an escape key but it does not.

Can anyone indicate how I can do this, and why the caps lock does not work using the above command?

My understanding is that this cannot be done in nvim's `.vimrc` file.

Below is `xev` output when pressing and then releasing `escape`, `keycode 9`

```
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x139, subw 0x0, time 75547017, (621,536), root:(792,564),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x139, subw 0x0, time 75547079, (621,536), root:(792,564),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False
```

Below is `xev` output when pressing and releasing `caps lock`, `keycode 66`

```
FocusOut event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  57  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x139, subw 0x0, time 75680956, (272,352), root:(443,380),
    state 0x2, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe5, Caps_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Hmm... You don't get a KeyPress event for Caps_Lock, but do get a KeyRelease. Something seems out of place. If you investigate `dmesg` warnings and errors, do you find some related to the keyboard?

Comment: @Quasímodo, thanks. I had a look in `dmesg` and in `journalctl` and could see no entry created by either `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape` or `xmodmap -e "keycode 9 = Caps_Lock"; xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape"`, suggested below,  which has the exact same effect, i.e., the escape key is remapped as caps lock, but the caps lock key is mapped to nothing. I used `diff file1 file2` where `file1` and `file2` are outputs of all of `journalctl` and `file1` is before the re-mapping and `file2` is after the re-mapping. I am using a Lenovo T430 thinkpad.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with xmodmap.
Swap the keys with.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 9 = Caps_Lock"; xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape"
```

afterwards this effect can be undone with

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Caps_Lock"; xmodmap -e "keycode 9 = Escape"
```

Not sure if this fits your needs, because it effects all processes within the x session.

Comment: Can you confirm this will transfer the modifying behavior of CapsLock to the new key too? I suspect `xmodmap` does not do that unless explicitly told so.

Comment: Hi @rudd, thanks. @Quasímodo, thanks. The `xmodmap -e "keycode 9 = Caps_Lock"; xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape"` keymapping has the exact same effect as  `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape`, i.e., the escape key is remapped as caps lock, but the caps lock key is mapped to nothing. I am using a Lenovo T430 thinkpad.

Comment: @Quasímodo, the command, `xmodmap -e "keycode 9 = Caps_Lock"; xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape"` does exactly the same as teh command I have been using i.e., `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape`. The escape key is re-mapepd as the caps lock key but the caps lock key is re-mapped as nothing. Both these commands do exactly the same thing on my Lenovo T430 keyboard.

Comment: `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape` works perfectly for me, this answer does not. Then the caps key triggers both caps and escape.

Answer (score 0):

[keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) is a universal way to rebind keys, but it doesn't have a way to rebind keys for specific programs. (It does have an experimental `keyd-application-mapper`, but it's only for windowed applications on specific window managers.) What you suggest would be impossible, or at least imperfect, as <kbd>escape</kbd> would be rebound to <kbd>capslock</kbd> whenever neovim is open, even if it's not currently focused/in use.

That said, keyd is "universal" because it works regardless of the session - X11, wayland, even TTY. I've been using it with no issues for months now.

To install and configure it, see the GitHub (linked above) or you can run these commands (this assumes you're using systemd):

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd
cd keyd
make
sudo make install
```

Now edit `/etc/keyd/default.conf` and paste the following:

```
[ids]

*

[main]

escape=capslock
capslock=escape
```

Then enable and start the keyd service:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now keyd
```